# Get text prior to edit from inside QLineEdit::textEdited()

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qlineedit, qvalidator

When I receive a `QLineEdit::textEdited()` signal, can I see what the text was prior to the edit? I need to compare the text as it was prior to the edit and the text after the edit.

The `textEdited()` signal has only one argument, which is the new text. Calling `QLineEdit::text()` also returns the new text.

Right now I can only think of is holding the old text in a QString, and updating that QString each time there is an edit, but then I need to account for programmatic changes (made via `QLineEdit::setText()`).

Or is there another way to intercept a text change (via validators perhaps) that would allow me to get the text prior to change and after change simultaneously? Preferably for user-changes only (non programmatic).

Comment: If you don't want to cache the old text, I think, using a validator is good alternative.

Comment: @vahancho I checked into that, but the `validate()` function gets only the new text, so they won't work, either. I guess I'll have to do the caching.

Comment: Yes, of course, you get the new text, but you get it **before** it is set to the line edit. Thus, if your validator does not accept that, line edit will still contain the old text.

Comment: Hm, that's weird, because I had tested it, and calling `lineEdit->text()` from inside `validate()` returns the new text.

Comment: `I need to compare the text as it was prior to the edit and the text after the edit.` -> for what purpose exactly?

Comment: @FinalContest I'm trying to implement  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033222/editable-multi-color-qlineedit, and this is a sub-problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now I can only think of is holding the old text in a QString, and updating that QString each time there is an edit, but then I need to account for programmatic changes (made via QLineEdit::setText())

Granted, I can also only think of that way, but please note that unlike textEdited(), textChanged() would allow you to even catch the programmatic changes as per documentation:

> Unlike textChanged(), this signal is not emitted when the text is changed programmatically, for example, by calling setText().