# changing The color of the words that Qt qtextedit already has

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to change The color of some words after the user wrote them into the qtextedit.
How can I do that?

for example, the user writes

[image]

I want to change it to

[image]

Comment: setStyleSheet() method should do it.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I don't get it why you need to know the condition? when the user pushes a key, I want to change the color of some words.

Comment: @nader, simple, because qt has some worderful validations that will resolve the problem in 2 lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QLineEdit::editingFinished()` signal to do it. This signal is emitted when the Return or Enter key is pressed or the line edit loses focus.

**Example.**

In your UI constructor:

```
QObject::connect(MainWindow::yourQLineEdit, &QLineEdit::editingFinished, 
                 this, &MainWindow::SetTextColorInQLineEdit);
```

In slot of class:

```
void MainWindow::SetTextColorInQLineEdit()
{
     MainWindow::yourQLineEdit->QWidget::setStyleSheet("your style for color");

     return;
}
```

**Hard way** - You need to override `QKeyEvent`

And check this enum  - `QEvent::KeyPress` and `QEvent::KeyRelease`

Check it out here:

`QEvent` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html

`QKeyEvent` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#text

Comment: it is not a QLineEdit. it is a QTextEdit and I don't want to change all texts but I want to change the color of some words.

Comment: @nader Try to rework this code for QTextEdit - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424003